# change default action of opening multiple files in dired

Tags: dired, files

Having marked a bunch of files in `dired-mode`, if I wanted to open all them at once, I press <kbd>F</kbd>. But, the problem is, all the selected files opens in their own separate window and now i've at least as many windows as the files I marked in `dired-mode`.

Is it possible to change this behaviour to open **only** the window of the topmost file in dired listing (while also opening the rest of the selected files in `dired-mode`, but not opening each of them in a separate window)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want that to happen all the time, try:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "F") (lambda ()
                       (interactive)
                       (find-file (car (dired-get-marked-files)))))
```

If you want all the files to get opened, you could try this variation:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "F")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (mapc #'find-file (reverse (dired-get-marked-files)))))
```

Comment: this does not open multiple files. Opens only one file which my point is on

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for? Open only the topmost file?

Comment: Ah I meant *only* the window of the topmost file to open, the rest of the buffers should be open in the background. By default it opens a new window for all buffers instead of opening just one. Cluttering my emacs frame.

Comment: There seems to be one minor problem. Your code works fine, except it also opens a new buffer empty buffer associated with the topmost file in the directory. Check here :- https://imgur.com/a/kSRwq (check first file in the minibuffer). Can I somehow stop this from happening ? and open only the first file i've selected

Comment: How about the revised version above?

Answer (score 0):

### Spacemace Config

Based on the awesome solution by @John Kitchin, I implemented in `spacemacs` at the `user-config` function. You can use one of the two functions below depending on your preference.

- Using the `spacemacs` specific keybinding based on (`general`).

```lisp
   (setq dired-dwim-target t)

   ;; --- another may to achieve ----
   (defun open-several-files-at-once ()
     (interactive)
     (mapc #'find-file (reverse (dired-get-marked-files))))
   (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "o" 'open-several-files-at-once)
```

- Method #2, Using the mapping based on natural emacs (works for any framework)

```lisp
   (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-o")
     (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (mapc #'find-file (reverse (dired-get-marked-files)))))
```

- Be aware to map to free-keys not used by `dired`.
- You should set `(setq dired-dwim-target t)` to open in same tab.